# Natural join works but not with all values

Tags: mysql, missing-data, natural-join

I can't understand whats happening...
I use two sql queries which do not return the same thing...
this one :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2 on t1.attribute1 = t2.attribute1
```

I get 10 rows

this other :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table1
```

I get 8 rows

With the `NATURAL JOIN` 2 rows aren't returned... I look for the missing lines and they are the same values ​​for the `attribute1` column ...

It's impossible for me.
If anyone has an answer I could sleep better ^^

Best regards
Max

Comment: `The SQL NATURAL JOIN is a type of EQUI JOIN and is structured in such a way that, columns with the same name of associated tables will appear once only.`

Comment: Is there any other column that is having same name in both table 1 and table 2 ? If so, then this natural join is looking for equality on that column also

Comment: yes there are other one with the same name. All the values of all colomn with the same name must be equal ?

Comment: @PraveenE The OP is doing a self join.  _Every_ column has a match on both sides of the join.

Comment: @MaximilienFaure That's the definition of `NATURAL JOIN`. It's a shorthand for `ON t1.att1 = t2.att1 AND t1.att2 = t2.att2 AND t1.att3 = t2.att3 ...` for all the same-named columns.

Comment: What @Barmar has explained is the reason for your issue

Comment: But if attribute1 is the only primary key , then both of your queries should return the same result

Comment: Thanks evrybody ;) It's finally logique (I'm a bit ashamed ^^' )

Comment: @PraveenE Presumably that's not the primary key.

Comment: Nothing to feel ashamed @MaximilienFaure

Comment: This: `SELECT * FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table1` will return exactly `table1` -- unless there are nullable fields and some are null. Natural JOIN is 'idempotent'. For a self-`JOIN ... on ...`, we need to see the schema.

Comment: @PraveenE Keys are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, the reason you are getting a different row count is that the natural join is connecting your self join using *all* columns.  All columns are being compared because the same table appears on both sides of the join.  To test this hypothesis, just check the column values from both tables, which should all match.

The moral of the story here is to avoid natural joins.  Besides not being clear as to the join condition, the logic of the join could easily change should table structure change, e.g. if a new column gets added.

Follow the link below for a small demo which tried to reproduce your current results.  In a table of 8 records, the natural join returns 8 records, whereas the inner join on one attribute returns 10 records due to some duplicate matching.

### Demo

Comment: I think there won’t be any risk if attribute1 will be the only primary key forever. What do you suggest @Tim

Comment: @PraveenE Why would you self-join on the primary key?

Comment: @PraveenE A natural join in the context of a self join is a bizarre choice to me.  I vote for avoiding natural joins altogether unless there is a very good reason to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'project away' the attribute you don't want used in the join e.g. in a derived table (`dt`):

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
       NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT attribute1 FROM table1 ) dt;
```